# Boundless Arrays?

Tags: c++, primes

I'm having some trouble. I wrote a code to find prime numbers up to a number, but for some reason, it gives me the error that I didn't define the number of elements in the array that I will be using. Is it possible to have an array where the number of elements isn't limited? Thanks :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int primer(int max);
int main()
{
    system("pause");
    return 0;
    primer(1000);
}

int primer(int max){
    int a[]=2;
    for (int i=2;i<=max;i++){
    prime=true;
    for (int ii=1;ii<=#a;ii++) {
    if i/a[ii]==math.floor(i/a[ii]) {
    prime=false;
    }
    }
    if prime==true {
    a[#a+1]=i;
    }
    }
    for (i=1;i<=#a;i++) {
    print(a[i]);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The code you posted is not valid C++. For example your if statements are not valid. Also, you have an uneven number of braces.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that code is not valid C++ in any way. You're using C++'s adaption of C's standard math library, and it's not a class of math functions. You are missing parentheses around your if statements' conditions, and you are assigning an integer to an array of integers that does not have a size specified. You are also missing a return value in primer, and probably a number of other small things that I missed.

Comment: For example, `int a[]=2;` is completely meaningless.

Comment: Also, "code" in this context is a non-countable quantity. "A code" is not right.

Comment: This question is the same as has been replaced by the 99% similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741629/c-vector-elements-count, that you just posted yourself.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. Use a [`std::vector`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Vector.html) or [`std::deque`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Deque.html).

Comment: STL is definitely the way to go for any collection in C++. [Here](http://www.cs.brown.edu/~jak/proglang/cpp/stltut/tut.html) is a quick, yet comprehensive, tutorial and [here](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/table_of_contents.html) is the main STL documentation.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I did. It worked, but the rest of my code is full of errors everywhere XD

Comment: @TimeCoder:  That's because the code is completely, utterly broken.  You can't just translate Lua to C++.  they are different languages.

Answer (score 1):

What is this # symbol that you're using everywhere?

Your line `int a[]=2` is incorrect.

You need to specify how big your array is going to be. For example, `int a[100]`, or 
`int a[] = {Values here}`.

That being said, you probably want a flexibly sized array like the vector class.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler needs to know how much space to allocate, and therefore requires you to state how many elements you have.

You could try using the STL vector instead of an array. This allows you to add as many elements as you want, without declaring the number right at the beginning.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/

Answer (score 1):

You are always 'limited', if only by the amount of memory which can allocate for the array.

Having said that, you will probably be fine using a `std::vector`.