# C++ Vector Elements Count

Tags: c++, translation, primes

In C++, using the vector header, how do I find the number of elements?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int primer(int max);
int main()
{
    system("pause");
    return 0;
    primer(1000);
}

int primer(int max){
    vector<int> a;
    a[1]=2;
    for (int i=2;i<=max;i++){
    bool prime=true;
    for (int ii=1;ii<=#a;ii++) {
    if i/a[ii]==math.floor(i/a[ii]) {
    prime=false;
    }
    }
    if prime==true {
    a[#a+1]=i;
    }
    }
    for (i=1;i<=#a;i++) {
    cout << a[i]);
    }
}
}
```

I originally wrote the code
for lua, and this is my attempt to translate it to C++. I would appreciate specifics, for example, a specific replacement for a bad line. I tried to replace #a with a.size, but it didn't work.

Revised:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int primer(int max);
int main()
{
    primer(5);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int primer(int max){
    vector<int> a;
    a[1]=2;
    for (int i=2;i<=max;i++){
    bool prime=true;
    for (int ii=0;ii<a.size();ii++) {
    if (i/a[ii]==floor(i/a[ii])) {
    prime=false;
    }
    }
    if (prime==true) {
    a.push_back(i);
    }
    }
    for (int iii=0;iii<=a.size();iii++) {
    cout << a[iii] << endl;
    }
}
```

It crashes without running. For what reason is this?

Comment: You're going to have range problems too. To use a vector properly, you'll have to either give it a size or use `push_back`.

Comment: @TimeCoder: No offense, but attempting to learn to program in C++ (edit) by posting on SO is going to waste both your time and ours.

Comment: The same as or a replacement for the 99% similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741436/boundless-arrays, that you just posted yourself.

Comment: @Tomalak: This one is trying to use `std::vector` as suggested in the answers to the other.  Yes they should have been linked, no it isn't a dupe.

Comment: @BenVoigt: A dupe is 100% similar. I said 99%.

Comment: @Tomalak No. One asked how to make arrays boundless. The second was for size of vectors. I checked online before and misunderstood.

Comment: @TimeCoder: They were close enough to raise an eyebrow.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal I'm a bit new to StackOverflow. Should I have posted that as an extension of that question within the question itself?

Comment: @TimeCoder: In my opinion, yes. Others may disagree. You'll catch on soon enough. :)

Comment: @Tomalak: They are only similar in that they are both about c++ vectors.  I'd hardly call that 99%.  @TimeCoder: No, you should not have extended your question.  Separate questions go in separate posts.

Comment: @PigBen: Are you kidding? The 32-line code snippets are practically identical! And the other one wasn't about vectors at all. Weird. He should have extended his original question, because he was merely building on the responses he was getting there. He should have addressed queries about those responses on *that* thread.

Comment: @Tomalak:  No, not kidding.  Yes, the code was practically identical.  That's to be expected, it's the same guy, and he's got a lot of problems with his code.  But the questions were distinct.  The first was about how to have a boundless array, the answer is to use a vector(which is why I said it's about vectors, even if he didn't know it when he asked the question).  The second is about how to get the size of a vector.  Two distinct questions, with two distinct answers, hence two posts.

Comment: @TimeCoder: The best way to do it is start a new question that begins with "Answers to my earlier question (give link) suggested that I use std::vector when I need an array whose size can change." and then go on with "But I can't figure out how to get the vector's size.  I tried `a.size` but it won't compile.  Here is my code ..."

Answer (score 9):

`a.size()`.

I would recommend using some sort of reference material, e.g. http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/.

Comment: Oh! .size(), not a property. That makes sense. Thanks :)

Comment: cplusplus.com is well-known to be full of mistakes. The Apache stdlib reference is superior.

Comment: @TimeCode:  There is not such thing as "property" in C++

Comment: @John Dibling, exactly. That was the mistake I made.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your immediate question:

```
a.size();  // use size as a function
```

But there are several other things wrong with your code:

```
vector<int> a;
a[1]=2;
```

Ordinarily you need to set the size of `a` beforehand, since C++ must allocate space for it. You can use `push_back()` though, which will incrementally add space as needed.

Also, C++ arrays start counting at 0:

```
for (int ii=1;ii<=#a;ii++) {
```

This should be

```
ii = 0
```

And since arrays start at 0, they end at `size() - 1`, not `size()`.

Comment: You spotted the off-by-one error and didn't fix the overrun it caused :(

Comment: Not to mention the fact that @TimeCoder is returning from `main` before he even calls the function!

Comment: @John [Ninefingers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741629/c-vector-elements-count/4741662#4741662) already caught that one.

Comment: @chris:  For a second there, I though you were calling me "ninefingers".  Made no sense at all!  lol

Answer (score 2):

```
for( int ii = 0; ii < a.size(); ++ii )
```

C and C++ array indexes start at zero and end at size-1, so you need to compare less-than, not less-than-or-equal-to.  vector follows the same rule.

Answer (score 1):

Another obvious problem that needs pointing out:

```
int main()
{
    system("pause");
    return 0;
    primer(1000);
}
```

Your function is never going to be called. Your app will exit when main returns.

Comment: XD Don't worry. Once I saw an error like that I could have fixed it quickly.

Comment: That's good to know! But it had to be said... I can't help myself.

Comment: Wow, I totally missed `main()`. I was so focused on all the issues with `primer()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 a[#a+1]=i;
```

changed to use size() becomes:

```
 a[ a.size() + 1 ] = i;
```

This is syntactically correct but guaranteed wrong. It should be:

```
 a.push_back(i);
```

Read the API referenced by Oli.

Comment: Actually cplusplus.com is well-known to be full of mistakes. The Apache stdlib reference is superior.

Comment: I have to admit I use the standard document directly.